# Is not a function error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

It gives me this problem - TypeError: Course.createCourse is not a function
from this code :

```
Course.createCourse(newCourse, function (err, course) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(course);
    });
```

I know its little info, however can someone help me? If you need more of the code i will submit it

Comment: The Course object does not have a function 'createCourse'. Make sure it is defined on the object.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is? What have you done to find out why createCourse doesn't exist? Did you check its source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Course is your model which you have imported in your controller and it does not have any function with such a name in your model thats why you are getting this error.

controller.js

```
Course.createCourse(newCourse, function (err, course) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(course);
});
```

model.js

```
Course.statics.createCourse = function(newCourse, callback){ 
    // your query will come here to create the course you want for example
   this.create(newCourse, callback);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot, you really saved me :)